# How to prove following Generalization of Hilbert Nullstellansatz

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This question is from assignment 1 of my algebraic geometry course. For theory, I have been following my class notes.

> Question: Let K be an arbitrary field, S be the set of all polynomials in $K[X_1, ..., X_n]$ which have no zeroes in $K^n$ and let A be an ideal in $K[X_1,...,X_n]$ . If $S\cap A =\varnothing$ , then show that $V_K(A)\neq \varnothing$.

Thoughts: $S\cap A=\varnothing$ implies that all elements of A have at least 1 zero in $K^n$. I have to prove that all elements of A have at least 1 common zero. But, why should all elements have at least one common zero? I am not sure what from the information given in the question would be useful to proceed foreward.

> Can you please give some hints so that I could able to proceed to proving this question?

Comment: It's better to use \varnothing ($\varnothing$) or \emptyset ($\emptyset$) for the empty set, rather than the Greek letter $\phi$. I've edited your post to fix this, I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

By Nullstellensatz, if $V_k(A)=\emptyset$, then the radical ideal of $A$ (and hence $A$) corresponds to the entire space $K[X_1,\dots X_n]$, so that $1=1^k\in A$

However $1$ has not roots in $K^n$, so that $1\in S$. This means $S\cap A\neq \emptyset$, a contradiction.

Comment: If $K=\Bbb{F}_q$ and $A=\langle X_1^q-X_1+1\rangle$ then $V_K(A)=\emptyset$ but $1\notin A$. True, $X_1^q-X_1+1\in S$, but how does that show in your argument?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I was supposing the case where the field is algebraically closed

Comment: @FedericoFallucca How does HNS implies that radical ideal corresponds to entire space?  Can you tell exactly the statement of the theorem you are using?

Comment: @Avenger This is called weak Nullstellensatz. You can find a briefly explanation here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz

Comment: @FedericoFallucca I have asked many other questions in Algebraic geometry and Manifolds , most of which are unanswered. Can you please help me with some of them?

Comment: @FedericoFallucca Can you also help me with the case when K is not algebraically closed?

Comment: @FedericoFallucca Kindly have a look in your spare time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If $K$ is algebraically closed, then this is the classical Hilbert's Nullstellensatz: $S$ consists of the constant non-zero polynomials, so $S \cap A = \emptyset$ if and only if $A$ is a proper ideal, if and only if (by the classical Nullstellensatz) $V_k(A) \neq \emptyset$. This is also the approach which @Federico Fallucca alludes to in their answer.

So what happens when $K$ is not algebraically closed? You start with a (WLOG finitely generated) ideal $A = (f_1, ..., f_k)$ for some $f_1, \ldots, f_k \in K[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$ and you know that all elements of $A$ have a root in $K^n$, and now you want to show that $f_1, \ldots, f_k$ also have a common root in $K^n$.

Let's think of $K = \mathbb{R}$ or $K = \mathbb{Q}$ for starters. In this case, you could observe that $f_1^2 + \ldots + f_k^2 \in A$ and hence has a root in $a \in K^n$. But then $f_1(a)^2 + \ldots + f_k(a)^2 = 0$ in $K$, which is only possible if $f_1(a) = \ldots = f_k(a) = 0$. So, we have found the desired common root of $f_1, \ldots, f_k$.

How would you generalise this observation to apply to an arbitrary field $K$?

Comment: How can you generalise to each field K? In the case of R and Q you have used that the field is an ordered field

Comment: Yes, the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is ordered was used to deduce that the homogeneous polynomial $H = T_1^2 + \ldots + T_k^2$ has no non-trivial zeroes, and then I could plug $f_1, \ldots, f_k$ into $H$ to obtain the desired conclusion. If $K$ is any non-algebraically closed field, I claim that we can always choose a homogeneous polynomial $H$ in $k$ variables over $K$ which has no non-trivial zeroes over $K$, and then the same reasoning applies.

Comment: @Bib-lost If K is algebralcally closed, then why S contains only of  constant non-zero polynomials?

Comment: @Avenger over an algebraically closed field, every non-constant polynomial has a root

Comment: @Bib-lost I got it. But why A can't be a proper ideal?

Comment: @Bib-lost Can you please reply to my comment above?

Comment: @Avenger I am not sure if I understood your question, but perhaps this helps: any non-zero constant polynomial is invertible, and in any ring, a proper ideal does not contain any invertible elements. Indeed, if $a$ is invertible, then any element $b$ of the ring can be written as $aa^{-1}b$, so if $a \in A$, then also $b \in A$ for any $a$.

Comment: @Bib-lost I am talking about 2nd line of your answer. I hope that makes it clear.

Comment: @Bib-lost I have asked quite a few other questions in ALgebraic geometry. Can you please help me with some of them also?